# Concatenating list results from multiple functions

Tags: python, data-structures

So, basically I've got a few functions that return `tuples`. Essentially of the form:

```
def function():
    return (thing, other_thing)
```

I want to be able to add several of these functions together in a straightforward way, like this:

```
def use_results(*args):
    """
    Each arg is a function like the one above
    """
    results = [test() for test in args]
    things = magic_function(results)
    other_things = magic_function(results)
```

Basically I have the data structure:

```
[([item_1, item_1], [item_2, item_2]), ([item_3, item_3], [item_4, item_4])]
```

and I want to turn it into:

```
[[item_1, item_1, item_3, item_3], [item_2, item_2, item_4, item_4]]
```

It seems like there's probably a nice pythonic way of doing this with a combination of `zip` and `*`, but it's not quite coming to me.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I feel kind of silly. I found an answer quickly after posting the question. I'm going to still keep this up in case there's a better solution though:

```
>>> import operator
>>> results = [([1,1], [2,2]), ([3,3], [4,4])]
>>> map(operator.add, *results)
[[1, 1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without importing any module, just built-in methods:

```
>>> results = [([1,1], [2,2]), ([3,3], [4,4])]
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(*results)]
[[1, 1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 4, 4]]
```

Or even this way as well:

```
>>> map(lambda s,t:s+t, *results)
```